# Create subdomain masking for each user in WordPress

Tags: htaccess, subdomains, nginx

I am trying to add subdomain URL for each user.

For eg: if my site has a user name as John then the URL which he will be sharing with his users is http://john.example.com and this should open the home page for my site http://example.com

My site is in Wordpress and hosted over WpEngine server I have enabled the wildcard domain mapping from WpEngine also added respective A records.

Now the issue is if I try to hit http://john.example.com WordPress redirects me to http://example.com

> instead I want it to stay and send a request like
>   http://john.example.com => http://example.com?user=john

do I need to write any htaccess/nginx rule for this?

Comment: Hi, Swapnil. What you want to achieve indeed seems like something to be solved by redirecting using capture groups (\w+)\.example.com and then using that info in variable $1 for on htaccess/NGINX. Therefore might it be better answered on Stackoverflow of Serverfault sites. With that said: as far as I now, WPE uses NGINX, and they have an interface to add your REGEX rules. Also, although this might fall outside their support scope, usually their support team are pretty helpful.